# Is there a way to get my own telegram status via BotFather using only client-side technology?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

So I want to get my telegram status (whether I'm online or offline) using BotFather API. I do not want to use any back-end, so is there a way of getting my status using Ajax/Js? BTW, I'm not concerned about security risks of not using a server-side solution.